# How to exchange commands and states between hardware interfaces (to generate a CAN message)

Tags: control, ros2

I have a robot with ackermann steering and front 2 wheel drive. The vehicle already has all the mobility controls executed by the ground mobility module. The autonomy layer (the computing unit) will communicate and send drive and steering commands to the existing vehicle mobility module via CAN.

I have 2 hardware interfaces, one for steering and one for wheel speed, BUT both signals are part of the same CAN message.
For example:

```
<ros2_control name="SteeringHarware" type="system">
   <hardware>
       <plugin>steering_hardware/SteeringHardware</plugin>
   </hardware>
   <joint name="steering_joint">
       <command_interface name="position"/>
       <state_interface name="velocity"/>
       <state_interface name="position"/>
   </joint>
</ros2_control>

<ros2_control name="WheelSpeedHardware" type="system">
   <hardware>
       <plugin>wheel_speed_hardware/WheelSpeedHardware</plugin>
   </hardware>
   <joint name="wheel_joint">
       <command_interface name="velocity"/>
       <state_interface name="velocity"/>
       <state_interface name="position"/>
   </joint>
</ros2_control>
```

I need to send a CAN message to the vehicle module containing both desired Steering and Wheel Speed.
I can't do it in the hardware interfaces since I wouldn't know what to put for the other one.
How should I approach this?
Initially I thought to have the hardware interfaces publish this information to a topic and then another node would take both info and send the CAN message. However, this breaks the separation of concerns.

I have looked into Actions and Transmissions and the latter seem the more appropriate.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Why are speed and steering both on the same message? Just split the messages. It's also hard to follow your description, though - I can't tell if you have one device making steering messages and one making throttle messages, or one making both and it going to one device *consuming* steering and one *consuming* throttle. But regardless, split the message. A throttle doesn't (shouldn't) know anything about a steering, and vice-versa. When you get a steering message, actuate steering. When you get a throttle message, actuate throttle.

Comment: What if I cannot change the way the vehicle CAN is setup? And, assuming I could split the messages, what if I need to pass other information in the message? I think, regardless of my specific use case, there are many cases where passing additional information to the hardware interface can be very useful.
Also, there is only 1 device on the vehicle that needs a CAN message with both steering and throttle. The device consumes that message and does the rest, commanding the two actuators.

Answer (score 0):

Moving these comments to an answer:

Why are speed and steering both on the same message? Just split the messages. It's also hard to follow your description, though - I can't tell if you have one device making steering messages and one making throttle messages, or one making both and it going to one device consuming steering and one consuming throttle. But regardless, split the message. A throttle doesn't (shouldn't) know anything about a steering, and vice-versa. When you get a steering message, actuate steering. When you get a throttle message, actuate throttle.

> What if I cannot change the way the vehicle CAN is setup? And, assuming I could split the messages, what if I need to pass other information in the message? I think, regardless of my specific use case, there are many cases where passing additional information to the hardware interface can be very useful. Also, there is only 1 device on the vehicle that needs a CAN message with both steering and throttle. The device consumes that message and does the rest, commanding the two actuators.

The questions you're asking are kind of the heart of engineering.

> what if I need to pass other information in the message?

You need to think through everything you're trying to do up front. If you think your messages should be throttle and steering, and then later you realize you need to also include a brake torque value, or a parking brake signal, or turn signal/headlight status, transmission gear selection, etc. - if you don't include the data you need from the start then you need to change the message later.

> What if I cannot change the way the vehicle CAN is setup?

This question is ambiguous. If you mean you can't change the CAN configuration in that you can't add or change messages then you're out of luck because you can't extend the messages or create other messages to cover all of your use cases. If you mean you can't change it in that you've got a steering controller generating steering signals and a throttle controller generating throttle signals then that's not an issue; have the steering controller send *steering-only* messages and the throttle controller send *throttle-only* messages.

You're missing a block diagram that explains how your network is setup, what the flow of messages are, etc.

The line I keep coming back to in your problem statement is this:

> I need to send a CAN message to the vehicle module containing both desired Steering and Wheel Speed. I can't do it in the hardware interfaces since I wouldn't know what to put for the other one.

This makes it sound like you have two different publishers, and each only knows how to fill out half of the CAN message. This is the basis for my suggestion to split the message. If you're not able to change the message then you could use a [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Debug_values), so a steering unit would publish `9999` or something for throttle, because it doesn't have a throttle, and then your receiver could look for the `9999` value and ignore that portion of the message.

But ultimately a steering device makes a steering message, and the receiver acts on that steering message. A throttle device makes a throttle message, and the receiver acts on that throttle message.